# Reading single byte with Asio::read

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, byte, boost-asio

Is it possible to read a single byte via asio::read?

I'm getting a single byte response and it seems wasteful to use the current buffering code:

```
        //Read the 1 byte reply
        char buffer[1];
        size_t bytesRead = asio::read(s, asio::buffer(buffer, 1));
        if(bytesRead < 1) return false;
```

Thanks.

Comment: You'll get more/better response if you frame your question better.  It is rather open ended and ambiguous as it is.  Try to add what problem you're having and what you're trying to achieve.  Some code would be useful as well.

Comment: how is your buffered implementation wasteful? Post your code.

Comment: Question re-framed, sample code added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, passing a buffer of a single byte is the only way.

Also it isn't wasteful. What is it that you're concerned about wasting?

Comment: Just thought allocating memory buffer takes more resources then defined variable, but I might not be familiar with Asio internals.

Comment: The memory buffer in your sample above is allocated on the stack. This is exactly the same as if you had defined a single char variable.

Comment: I actually thought that buffer function creates some internal buffers as well, but now I see it actually just maps the pre-defined stuck buffer so it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

boost::asio is implemented on top of Windows' overlapped I/O TCP Winsock implementation.  There's no way around buffers, etc. in such an implementation.

Comment: Linux is the target platform.